# mercedes s350 automatic transmission (722.906 ) is cutting out

Tags: automatic-transmission, mercedes-benz

i recently diy changed the transmission oil & filter and all shifting solenoids(re-manufactured) in my 722.9 box in an 06 S350 after it just started slipping and the obd scanner showed faulty solenoids. the box was not low on oil

filled the transmission with the right red oil from benz(payed $160 just for the oil), about 9 litres and dropped the excess amount at 45C degree.

after the oil change the car drove normal for a week, after a week the box started to cut out while driving as if it goes into neutral (engine revs high) and then back in gear. the next morning it would not go, when you put it in gear, it rolls slowly with no power, just enough to roll on flat ground (same with reverse), if you hit the accelerator the engine revs but the car does not move(not a limp mode). i suspected the transmission pump because the transmission has no energy in it, but i am doubting it because there is no noising coming when i rev the engine. i am scanning it with Autel Maxicom MK808 scanner, no faults are showing for the tranny. what could it be? could the solenoids be bad and not show on the scanner?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!